# Recyclerview duplicates items from firebase becuase of a nested SingleValueEvent

Tags: android, database, firebase, android-recyclerview, duplicates

Basically I'm receiving these items across the app on other tabs properly.
This tab is actually the "new" tab. It should display all of the items from the server.

The code of receiving all of the data:

```
 private void pullDataFromFirebase(String dataType) {

    switch (dataType) {
        case "Audio":
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Audio Categories");
            database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    audioCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();

                    Category category = new Category();

                    for (DataSnapshot catData : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            category = catData.getValue(Category.class);
                        audioCategories.add(new Category(category.getImageUrl(), category.getTitle(), category.getDateOfPublish()));
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < audioCategories.size(); i++) {
                        catTitle = audioCategories.get(i).getTitle();
                        catRef = database.child(catTitle).child("Items");

                        catRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Item item = data.getValue(Item.class);
                                    item.setKindOfItem("Audio");
                                    item.setLinkToEvent("Audio item doesn't have a link");
                                    items.add(new Item(item.getImageUrl(), item.getTitle(), item.getSummary(), item.getembeddedIDOrPowerLinkID(),item.getLinkToEvent(),item.getKey(), item.getDateOfPublish(), item.getKindOfItem()));
                                }
                                pullDataFromFirebase("Video");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }

            });

            break;
        case "Video":

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Video Categories");
            database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    videoCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();

                    Category category = new Category();

                    for (DataSnapshot catData : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        category = catData.getValue(Category.class);
                        videoCategories.add(new Category(category.getImageUrl(), category.getTitle(), category.getDateOfPublish()));
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < videoCategories.size(); i++) {
                        catTitle = videoCategories.get(i).getTitle();
                        catRef = database.child(catTitle).child("Items");

                        catRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        Item item = data.getValue(Item.class);
                                        item.setKindOfItem("Video");
                                        item.setLinkToEvent("Video item doesn't have a link");
                                        items.add(new Item(item.getImageUrl(), item.getTitle(), item.getSummary(), item.getembeddedIDOrPowerLinkID(),item.getLinkToEvent(),item.getKey(), item.getDateOfPublish(), item.getKindOfItem()));
                                    }
                                    pullDataFromFirebase("Event");
                                } else {
                                    Log.i("VIDEO_CAT_EMPTY","One of the video categories is empty.");
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }

            });

            break;
        case "Event":
            DatabaseReference database;
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events");

            database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Item item = data.getValue(Item.class);
                        item.setKindOfItem("Event");
                        items.add(new Item(item.getImageUrl(), item.getTitle(), item.getSummary(), item.getembeddedIDOrPowerLinkID(),item.getLinkToEvent(),item.getKey(), item.getDateOfPublish(), item.getKindOfItem()));
                    }
                    setNewsRecyclerView();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

While writing this post I was investigating even further and now I know that after I'm uploading a new Audio Category in my app this is happening. 
The first audio category is just duplicating the event items, and from 2 and above I can see that the video items in the list are duplicating themselves as well. **NOTE: Audio isn't duplicating itself.

I can understand that this is happening due to the nature of the function. I'm calling on OnCreateView to the

> pullDataFromFirebase("Audio")

which is the first function in the series.
These are firebase functions and to populate my local RecyclerView I MUST call them this way since they are A-synchronous.
I think this is happening because of the order. (Audio first then Video then Event) it is replicating the behavior of a nested for loop.

Maybe I'm wrong. 
Suggestions?

EDIT: I might found a way, I can add to the Item object a String which is a unique ID to each member of the array list... this is not optimal but It can solve the problem. (didn't check that yet.)

Comment: Please add your database structure and the exact values you want to get.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for the reply.
https://imgur.com/a/HpJW3
These are the screenshots of the data, 
You can see here Audio items below Audio categories.
Videos built the same
Events are more straight forward.. They are just below "Events".

Comment: I cannot understand much. I need a more detailed screenshot, including you root. Also that does not contain words in your language, because i cannot write them. Also please tell me the exact values you want to get, by example.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks again, I hope that this screen shot will do it: 
https://imgur.com/4rwQbrv

The words in my language I have translated it for you and in general I have mapped the database so it will be easier to read it according to the code. (Firebase references and such) 

I want to get all of the Audio items + All of the Video Items + all of the event items from all of the database. (From all of the video +audio categories of course ) The tab in the app will show all of the server database.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh My God! 
I cannot believe it that it was so simple and it slipped away from me. 
The answer is :

To understand the logic:

The nested OnDataChange has two places to execute the desired function (that will work on the local recyclerview) which are after the "for" that I'm gathering with it the information from the server and populating the Item.class and the array list.
I have executed both of the `pullDataFromFirebase("Video")`
and `pullDataFromFirebase("Event")`
on the 2nd OnDataChange, it was actually a syntax error which in some cases(depends on the current data situation in the server) led to multiplying of both of these functions.

Example from the code:

```
            case "Video":

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Video Categories");
            database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        videoCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();
                        Category category = new Category();

                        for (DataSnapshot catData : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            category = catData.getValue(Category.class);
                            videoCategories.add(new Category(category.getImageUrl(), category.getTitle(), category.getDateOfPublish()));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < videoCategories.size(); i++) {
                            catTitle = videoCategories.get(i).getTitle();
                            catRef = database.child(catTitle).child("Items");

                            catRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            Item item = data.getValue(Item.class);
                                            item.setKindOfItem("Video");
                                            item.setLinkToEvent("Video item doesn't have a link");
                                            items.add(new Item(item.getImageUrl(), item.getTitle(), item.getSummary(), item.getembeddedIDOrPowerLinkID(), item.getLinkToEvent(), item.getKey(), item.getDateOfPublish(), item.getKindOfItem()));
                                        }
           **************THE FUNCTION WAS LOCATED HERE ***************

                                    } else {
                                        Log.i("ONE_OR_MORE_VIDEO_EMPTY", "One or more of the categories are empty.");
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i("VIDEO_CAT_EMPTY", "There are no video categories to show");
                    }

      **************Actually the Function Should Be here ***************

                    pullDataFromFirebase("Event");
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }

            });
```

So what can we learn from that? 
When you "play" with nested SingleValueEventListener or actually any nested-style function, BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL.

Thanks Again Alex.